# Cannot load prolog source file

Tags: prolog

I was working in Prolog and all of the sudden when I tried to load my source file I started getting this `error: uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:5) , | ] or operator expected in list'),read_term/3)`

I created an empty source file test.pl and tried loading it as well `[test.pl]`. but I receive the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you typed exactly `[test.pl]` as you wrote in your question, then the error is due to not using an atom as the argument to the list notation shortcut to compile and load files. Try instead `['test.pl']` or simply `[test]`.

Comment: GnuProlog give that exact message